# Кодировка файла

Tags: utf

Привет всем!

Как можно создать файл в кодировке utf-8 ?
Псть файл в кодировке windows-1251, и я их копирую в другую папку.
Сначала создаю для записи: fopen
потом пишу :  fwrite
но файл все равно в 1251, я туда пишу строку в utf-8
но кодировка самого файла utf-8

Comment: У файлов нет свойства "кодировка"...

Comment: Может я не так спросил, у меня есть проект на вин-1251 мне нужно что бы он корректно показывал кириллицу, указания кодировки i

Comment: Не дописывает до конца комменты, хотя пишет что осталось 420 символов может потому что с телефона

Comment: Короче чтобы текст прописанный ил коду ввводился нормально надо создать в другой папке файл в кодировке утф-8, туда скопировать текст из файла в 1251, сохранит и переписать обратно на диск

Comment: Не предлагайте установку кодировки через Хидер в pho, проставлением в тайтле страницы и другие известные методы

Comment: Интересует просто софтина что бы делала подобную вещ